# Conditionally SELECT the MAX date Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to tackle a problem that has crippled me the last few weeks.

I have the following 4 tables:

**tblPO**

```
| PO Number |    Date    |
|:---------:|:----------:|
| PO2882274 |  6/4/2019  |
| PO1808776 |  6/1/2019  |
| PO1400048 |  5/21/2019 |
| PO6436130 |  4/19/2019 |
| PO4144242 |  2/21/2019 |
| PO7576919 |  1/15/2019 |
| PO1400048 | 12/24/2018 |
| PO6436130 | 11/15/2018 |
| PO6436130 |  1/1/2019  |
```

**tblWO**

```
| WO Number |    Date   |
|:---------:|:---------:|
|  SALE600  | 4/26/2018 |
|  SALE958  | 3/31/2018 |
|  SALE556  |  4/4/2018 |
|  SALE594  |  8/4/2018 |
|  SALE755  | 4/16/2018 |
|  SALE539  | 3/14/2018 |
|  SALE745  | 6/25/2018 |
|  SALE539  |  1/3/2019 |
|  SALE539  |  4/2/2018 |
```

**tblMO**

```
| MO Number |    Date   |
|:---------:|:---------:|
|  MAKE551  | 5/20/2019 |
|  MAKE563  | 1/22/2019 |
|  MAKE504  | 1/27/2019 |
|  MAKE588  | 1/13/2019 |
|  MAKE542  |  1/4/2019 |
|  MAKE614  |  3/8/2019 |
|  MAKE658  | 1/10/2019 |
|  MAKE563  |  1/1/2018 |
|  MAKE551  |  1/1/2019 |
```

and **tblTRX**

```
| Required Date |     Element    | PO Number | WO Number | MO Number | Otherdata |
|:-------------:|:--------------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|
|   4/22/2019   | Purchase Order | PO2882274 |           |           |    foo    |
|    1/3/2018   |   Work Order   |           |  SALE600  |           |    foo    |
|   3/22/2019   |   Make Order   |           |           |  MAKE551  |    foo    |
|    5/1/2019   |   Make Order   |           |           |  MAKE563  |    foo    |
|   7/24/2018   |   Make Order   |           |           |  MAKE504  |    foo    |
|   4/28/2018   |   Make Order   |           |           |  MAKE588  |    foo    |
|    7/4/2018   |   Make Order   |           |           |  MAKE542  |    foo    |
|   11/9/2018   |   Make Order   |           |           |  MAKE614  |    foo    |
|   10/2/2018   | Purchase Order | PO7576919 |           |           |    foo    |
|   9/29/2018   |   Work Order   |           |  SALE958  |           |    foo    |
|   6/18/2018   |   Work Order   |           |  SALE556  |           |    foo    |
|   10/9/2018   |   Work Order   |           |  SALE594  |           |    foo    |
|   4/22/2018   |   Work Order   |           |  SALE755  |           |    foo    |
|    4/3/2018   |   Work Order   |           |  SALE539  |           |    foo    |
|   5/11/2018   | Purchase Order | PO6436130 |           |           |    foo    |
```

A few notes:

- The primary keys in tblPO, tblMO, and tblWO **can repeat themselves**, so I need to select the `MAX` date (the  most recent)
- I cannot change the structure of these tables, nor do I have admin / write access to them

I am attempting to write a SQL query that would allow me to conditionally select the `Date` from the `tblxO` based on what element it is, and then joining on its unique identifier.

So for example...

```
| Required Date |     Element    | PO Number | WO Number | MO Number |  TrxDate  | Otherdata |
|:-------------:|:--------------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|
|   4/22/2019   | Purchase Order | PO2882274 |           |           |  6/4/2019 |    foo    |
|    1/3/2018   |   Work Order   |           |  SALE600  |           | 4/26/2018 |    foo    |
|   3/22/2019   |   Make Order   |           |           |  MAKE551  | 5/20/2019 |    foo    |
|    5/1/2019   |   Make Order   |           |           |  MAKE563  | 1/22/2019 |    foo    |
|   7/24/2018   |   Make Order   |           |           |  MAKE504  | 1/27/2019 |    foo    |
|   4/28/2018   |   Make Order   |           |           |  MAKE588  | 1/13/2019 |    foo    |
|    7/4/2018   |   Make Order   |           |           |  MAKE542  |  1/4/2019 |    foo    |
|   11/9/2018   |   Make Order   |           |           |  MAKE614  |  3/8/2019 |    foo    |
|   10/2/2018   | Purchase Order | PO7576919 |           |           | 1/15/2019 |    foo    |
|   9/29/2018   |   Work Order   |           |  SALE958  |           | 3/31/2018 |    foo    |
|   6/18/2018   |   Work Order   |           |  SALE556  |           |  4/4/2018 |    foo    |
|   10/9/2018   |   Work Order   |           |  SALE594  |           |  8/4/2018 |    foo    |
|   4/22/2018   |   Work Order   |           |  SALE755  |           | 4/16/2018 |    foo    |
|    4/3/2018   |   Work Order   |           |  SALE539  |           |  1/3/2019 |    foo    |
|   5/11/2018   | Purchase Order | PO6436130 |           |           | 4/19/2019 |    foo    |
```

The `TrxDate` would follow a sort of logic like:

> If the Element is Purchase Order, then look in the Purchase Order
>   table for the maximum date for the given row's purchase order number

I have attempted the following:

```
CASE
    WHEN TRIM(UPPER(ELEMENT)) = 'PURCHASE ORDER' THEN (SELECT MAX(tblPO.Date) FROM tblPO INNER JOIN tblTRX ON tblTRX.PO_Number = tblPO.PO_Number)
    WHEN TRIM(UPPER(ELEMENT)) = 'WORK ORDER' THEN (SELECT MAX(tblWO.Date) FROM tblWO INNER JOIN tblTRX ON tblTRX.WO_Number = tblWO.WO_Number)
    WHEN TRIM(UPPER(ELEMENT)) = 'MAKE ORDER' THEN (SELECT MAX(tblMO.Date) FROM tblMO INNER JOIN tblTRX ON tblTRX.MO_Number = tblPO.MO_Number)
    ELSE NULL
    AS Trx_Date
```

which does yield data, however, it is selecting the overall max for the `tblPO` (or other) table, and not just for the specific `PO_Number` for that row.

I logically know I am incorrect but cannot work around this hurdle.

Comment: I did need to spoof this data to not be company proprietary so if there are slight inconsistencies please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not reference your base table in the subqueries again:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN TRIM(UPPER(ELEMENT)) = 'PURCHASE ORDER' THEN (SELECT MAX(tblPO.Date) FROM tblPO WHERE tblTRX.PO_Number = tblPO.PO_Number)
    WHEN TRIM(UPPER(ELEMENT)) = 'WORK ORDER' THEN (SELECT MAX(tblWO.Date) FROM tblWO WHERE tblTRX.WO_Number = tblWO.WO_Number)
    WHEN TRIM(UPPER(ELEMENT)) = 'MAKE ORDER' THEN (SELECT MAX(tblMO.Date) FROM tblMO WHERE tblTRX.MO_Number = tblPO.MO_Number)
    ELSE NULL END
  AS Trx_Date
FROM tblTRX
```

should work. As otherwise the binding to your base table is broken.

> Reason - another way to write your query is the following:
>
> ```
> SELECT
>   CASE
>     WHEN TRIM(UPPER(ELEMENT)) = 'PURCHASE ORDER' THEN (SELECT MAX(tblPO.Date) FROM tblPO INNER JOIN tblTRX AS T1 ON T1.PO_Number = tblPO.PO_Number)
>     WHEN TRIM(UPPER(ELEMENT)) = 'WORK ORDER' THEN (SELECT MAX(tblWO.Date) FROM tblWO INNER JOIN tblTRX AS T2 ON T2.WO_Number = tblWO.WO_Number)
>     WHEN TRIM(UPPER(ELEMENT)) = 'MAKE ORDER' THEN (SELECT MAX(tblMO.Date) FROM tblMO INNER JOIN tblTRX AS T3 ON T3.MO_Number = tblPO.MO_Number)
>   ELSE NULL
>   AS Trx_Date
> FROM tblTRX AS T4
> ```
>
> If you now have a closer look to this statement, you see that there is no condition in the subqueries that reduces the number of values depending on the outer table.

Comment: Could you please expand on your answer to explain why what I did didn't work vs why just the `WHERE` does?

Comment: @JerryM. See my anwser below, I explained why your joins don't do what you expect

Answer (score 1):

First of all

> The primary keys in tblPO, tblMO, and tblWO can repeat themselves

There are no such things as repeating primary keys. If you have repeating ids those ids are not primary keys.

Now to answer your question : Your case fails because your inner joins embeded in the case all refeers to distinct instances of tblTrx, (you could have 4 separate 'AS' to name them, one for each WHEN statement and one in the main FROM), there is nothing restricting the MAX to your current transaction.

Two solutions :

1) correct your case, replacing the joins with 'where' clauses to have only one instance of tblTRX to lookup

```
CASE
  WHEN TRIM(UPPER(ELEMENT)) = 'PURCHASE ORDER' THEN (SELECT MAX(tblPO.Date) FROM tblPO WHERE tblTRX.PO_Number = tblPO.PO_Number)
  WHEN TRIM(UPPER(ELEMENT)) = 'WORK ORDER' THEN (SELECT MAX(tblWO.Date) FROM tblWO WHERE tblTRX.WO_Number = tblWO.WO_Number)
  WHEN TRIM(UPPER(ELEMENT)) = 'MAKE ORDER' THEN (SELECT MAX(tblMO.Date) FROM tblMO WHERE tblTRX.MO_Number = tblPO.MO_Number)
  ELSE NULL END
 AS Trx_Date
```

2) Use proper joins (This will be much better to build upon)

```
SELECT
  [Required Date],
  [Element]
  MAX (
   COALESCE( tblPO.Date , tblWO.Date, tblMO.Date )
  ) AS Trx_Date
FROM tblTRX AS T
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPO AS P ON T.PO_Number = P.PO_Number AND TRIM(UPPER(ELEMENT)) = 'PURCHASE ORDER'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblWO AS W ON T.WO_Number = W.WO_Number AND TRIM(UPPER(ELEMENT)) = 'WORK ORDER'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblMO AS M ON T.MO_Number = M.MO_Number AND TRIM(UPPER(ELEMENT)) = 'MAKE ORDER'
 GROUP BY 
   [Required Date],
   [Element]
```

Comment: I don't think you're join approach is very beneficial. When joining you should first filter only the newest record per "ID" of the subtables and join them instead of grouping the resultset, which might lead to different result depending if the "ID's" intersect or not...

Comment: That's the point, There might be use cases where they need all those entries, it's always more robust.

I reckon that the best (most efficient in memory) way in this case is not a MAX but setting a rownum grouped by [PWM]O_Number and ordered by date

Comment: I edited to use a coalesce, much cleaner. Also illustrates than in the e.g. by OP there might be several PO or several WO or several MO but never simulateneous orders of different kinds.